# Using proper OOP patterns to build a game in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm creating a game that requires certain parts of the game to interact with others. Here are my declarations.

```
world = new World();
player = new Player(world);
touchpad = new Touchpad(player);
background = new Background(player);
```

- `player` needs information from the `world` in order to handle
  collisions (modify player's position).
- `touchpad` needs to have a reference of the player to
  control/modify its position.
- `background` needs information on
  the player's location in order to change colors based on where it is.

I'm not sure if this is a proper way to go about. I've read some things where my declarations should not depend on what was written above, and **should** be able to be moved around randomly and still function. Is this correct?

I'm not sure where to go with this exactly. Should some info contained in some of the classes be put somewhere else? Should I create more classes to further break down what I have right now? Am I doing it completely wrong and should be taking a different approach?

Comment: Does your code looks readable, maintainable, testable to you? If so, why worry? People tend to over-engineer things. Keep it that way, and when a problem appears, then start thinking about a different, better design that would solve this problem, and start refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read some things where my declarations should not depend on what was written above, and should be able to be moved around randomly and still function.

This sounds like it is arguing for [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). This is good generally.

**Example**, this `TouchPad` class can only be used to move a `Player`:

```
public class TouchPad {
   public TouchPad(Player player) {
   }
}
```

Where as this `TouchPad` can can control any object that's class implements `Controllable`.

```
public interface Controllable {
   void move(int x, int y);
}

public class TouchPad {
   public TouchPad(Controllable player) {
   }
}

public class Player implements Controllable {
```

This is cleaner as it limits the functionality of `Player` available to `TouchPad`. And `TouchPad` doesn't know it is controlling a `Player`.

You can take two approaches, write the code first and then "refactor" it so that it is looser, or start your approach looser. You tend to do the former by default with experience and when doing [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)/[test driven developement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Comment: And to add to that, watch for which objects know about other objects and which objects initiate actions. So it might make sense that a player knows about the world, but the world not to know about players (like you've got). OTOH should a touch pad know about a player or should it be the other way around? I'd probably have a register(player) function on the touch pad which would be told of events and then the player or world would decide what to do with the  events.

Answer (score 0):

What you're creating above is a **has a relationship**. So I think that describing it to yourself can help you - like this:

```
Controller controller = new Keybord(); //use interfaces. There may be more controllers in the future.
Player player = new SinglePlayer(controller); //as a person who plays a game. Maybe interface won't be needed. Player has a controller rather than controller has a player.

Hero hero = new SomeHero();
Word world = SomeUglyWorld(hero); //a world has a hero rather than a hero has a world. World can define something like gravity and so on.
Level level = new SomeLevel(world); //level can begin, end, have some check points. Level has a world -> has a hero.
Level level = new SomeOtherLevel(theSameOrDifferentWorld);
Game game = new Game(player, listOfLevels);  //as a game itself, it can iterate through the levels, start/stop them. Game has levels -> worlds -> heros. Game has a player.
```

All of the above(but the Game) is created using interfaces.

I think this can be found as helpful and important, as you will be able to switch levels/heroes/worlds in a flexible manner. You won't have strong connections between the objects (world will know only what it can do to the hero but not how it is done).

It's also useful to keep your classes as small as possible so that each class is responsible for a small part of a program. The same goes to methods.